# QApplication stuck in constructor

Tags: c++, qt

I have following code compiled with Visual Studio 2013, x64 target and linked with QT 5.4. It compiles fine and it generates the executable.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow mainWindow;

    mainWindow.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

If I try to run it from the IDE it gets stuck on the line: `QApplication app(argc, argv);`, but if I run the executable directly works as expected, it creates a small windows and the process gets closed after the windows is closed. I have same behavior in both debug and release configurations.

Is anything wrong with the code? What may cause this weird problem?

EDIT: It gets stuck is something like an infinite loop inside. Unfortunately the call stack doesn't help me much about that because it looks like this if I hit "break all":

```
Qt5Core.dll!0000000066ae3291()  Unknown
Qt5Core.dll!0000000066aa941f()  Unknown
Qt5Core.dll!0000000066ad0da7()  Unknown
Qt5Core.dll!0000000066b302b6()  Unknown
Qt5Core.dll!0000000066b2e3a1()  Unknown
Qt5Gui.dll!000007fee4fcde9f()   Unknown
Qt5Widgets.dll!000000006441e1dc()   Unknown
MyAwesomeApp.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv) Line 10  C++
```

EDIT1:

After changing the configuration to Win32, it works as expected when started from IDE.

Comment: What means "... it gets stuck on the line"?

Comment: is that a breakpoint?

Comment: Are you sure you have your dll dependencies figured out? Did you run windeploy?

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus I have a post build step to copy dlls to the output folder, something like: xcopy /d $(QT_DIR)\bin\Qt5Core.dll $(OutDir). I'm running the executable directly from the output folder, without any intermediary step.

Comment: @Felics yeah that probably won't work (as written). The Qt dll's have to be put in a particular directory structure, and additionally the dll dependencies aren't as simple as they used to be in Qt4. Change your postbuild step to something like: ${QTDIR}bin/windeployqt.exe ${TARGET_NAME}, using the appropriate syntax for your IDE.